# Does amazon or heroku provide a worker role service

Tags: azure, heroku, amazon-web-services, azure-worker-roles, worker

Similar to an Azure worker role, does amazon web services or Heroku offer a service that would be useful for a worker process or recurring worker role.  For example, an hourly job that would download a file from a url and parse it into a database or insert it into a dynamo db.

Ideally it would have a status dashboard web interface that would let you see the status of jobs, errors in jobs, etc...

Comment: It sounds like the feature you are looking for is a combination of Azure WebJobs combined with the Scheduler. That has all of the features you are mentioning. Time based triggers and a dashboard for status and errors that occurred in jobs.

Comment: Heroku has workers as part of the cedar stack. You will need to pull in other services for scheduling.

Comment: also noticed that amazon has something called simple work flow which might fit the need as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku has a concept of 'worker dynos' to which you can assign to process background jobs, or the other tasks you had asked about.

More information:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing